# Autotransformer equivalent circuit

Tags: power, transformer, analog, power-electronics, electromagnetism

I am trying to find an equivalent circuit for autotransformer. But there is no any source about it. I tried to solve something about it. Can anyone have any idea about it?

[image]

Comment: isn't it just treated as a transformer with the two coils connected together?

Comment: Your pictures show that you are nearly there. But, an equivalent circuit that goes how far? Maybe show the equivalent circuit of a regular transformer so that people know how equivalent you want it to be?